# How to create a nested class selector?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML like below.

```
<div class="div14">
    <custom-element class="custom-class">
        <span class="welcome">welcome text</span>
        .....
    </custom-element>
</div>
```

I want to select welcome class under div14 class.

I have tried below selector but its not working. Is there any way to select welcome class under div14 class?

```
.div14.welcome {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Put a space between `.div14` and `.welcome`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put space between your selectors

`.div14.welcome` ...... means select all elements having both `div14` and `welcome` class

`.div14 .welcome` ...... means select all elements having `.welcome` class inside `.div14` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.div14 .welcome {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div14">
  <custom-element class="custom-class">
    <span class="welcome">welcome text</span> .....
  </custom-element>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right, to select something inside something else it's

`.div14 .welcome{ //your css}`

You need a space in there